# Why are standard errors larger for conditional effects versus marginal effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, standard-error, conditional-expectation, marginal-effect

I am estimating the conditional and marginal effects for a continuous by continuous interaction in a linear mixed effects model. The standard errors for the conditional effects are much larger than those of the marginal effects. Why is this the case?

**Conditional Effects Plot**
[image]
**Marginal Effects Plot**
[image]

If it helps, I used the `ggpredict()` and the `ggeffect()` functions in the `ggeffects` package in R to make these plots.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the code used to fit the model, the code to generate the plots, and even better a reproducible short example with data. Confusion and questions may arise otherwise. In my case for instance, you state that you are analyzing a "continuous by continuous interaction", but then I see three groups in the legend of the plots... I would not have expected a categorical variable there, based on the above statement.
Bottom line: sharing the code and data would increase the likelihood that we are in the same understanding of the problem.